# dmidecode reveals something with Internal Reference Designator: NUDE

Tags: bios, asus, dmidecode

**Internal Reference Designator: NUDE**.

Anyone know what this is?  I googled and came up empty handed.
I came across this when troubleshooting an issue with my USB ports.

Motherboard is a three month old **Asus Maximus XI Code**, running Linux Mint 18.3, kernel 4.15.0-52-generic #56~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 12:03:31 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux:

```
   [15:47:17] root@home: /etc/default > dmidecode --type connector
    ...
    Handle 0x0016, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
    Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: NUDE
        Internal Connector Type: Other
        External Reference Designator: Not Specified
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: Other
```

Answer (score 2):

It probably refers to the **Node** connector, that would pass hardware monitoring information (fan speeds, temperatures etc.) from a compatible PSU or fan extension card. It's (briefly) described on [page 1-19 of the motherboard manual.](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/ROG_MAXIMUS_XI_CODE/E14941_ROG_MAXIMUS_XI_CODE_UM_V3_WEB.pdf) So it probably should actually be **NODE**.

The "Internal Reference Designator" should normally match the connector identifier silkscreened next to the connector on the motherboard. But in this case, I guess whoever customized the Z390 series BIOS for this particular motherboard was not a native English speaker and made a typo.

Given human nature, I think there's pretty good chance that the person who made that mistake is already made extremely aware of it, and that on the next BIOS version, the typo will be unceremoniously fixed.

Comment: Your comment appears when I have the question under my eyes.  I was actually thinking along the same lines, having seen NODE in the manual. But this remains a tentative conclusion though. In any event, thanks for taking the time to try to address this in a serious fashion.

Comment: Since you seem to have that specific motherboard, you could take the list of connectors from the motherboard manual and the `dmidecode --type connector` output, match them up with each other and see what possibilities are left for the potentially-misspelled one. If it turns out there is nothing else it could be, then I think the conclusion would be quite strong.

Comment: Done that, and it looks like you were correct.